# Deal with Null object references through Interfaces

Tags: vb.net, interface

I have an object `Foo` which I do not own (third-party assembly) and want to pass through an interface `IFoo`.

Before passing everything via interfaces, I had a `Function TryGet(Name As String) as Foo`. This function would return `Nothing` when the name could not be found.

Now refactoring everything into interfaces, I have `Function TryGet(Name As String) as IFoo`.

The implemenation of `IFoo` is:

```
Public Class SuperFoo
    Implements IFoo

    Private ThisFoo As Foo

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(MyFoo As Foo)
        Me.ThisFoo = MyFoo
    End Sub

    Public Property Value As String Implements IFoo.Value
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFoo.Value
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.ThisFoo.Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Class AnotherClass

    Function TryGet(Name as String) as IFoo
        Dim MyFoo as Foo = InitialTryGetFunction(Name)
        Return New SuperFoo(MyFoo)
    End Function

End Class
```

So that I maintain my original code logic, I would like to be able to make the reference to the `SuperFoo` object null when `InitialTryGetFunction` returns a null reference.

Obviously I could just add some code to `If` the `Return New SuperFoo(MyFoo)` statement, but I was wondering if this could be done from the `SuperFoo` constructor?

Also, am I doing the switch to interfaces (mostly for the purpose of Unit Testing) correctly?

Comment: *"I would like to be able to make the SuperFoo object null"*.  Just for the record, that makes no sense as written.  You can't make an object null.  Null is, by definition, no object.  A reference is null when it refers to no object so you want to return a `SuperFoo` reference that refers to no object.

Comment: I would like to be able to make the reference to the SuperFooobject null when InitialTryGetFunction returns a null reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a widening operator in `SuperFoo` that converts `Foo` to `SuperFoo`. As operators are `Shared`, you can return `Nothing` if the given `Foo` is `Nothing`, otherwise return a new `SuperFoo`.

```
Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal x As Foo) As SuperFoo
    Return If(x Is Nothing, Nothing, New SuperFoo(x))
End Operator
```

VB.Net is quite good in resolving, I think you can then even return it directly like this (untested, no warranty):

```
    Function TryGet(Name as String) as IFoo
        Return InitialTryGetFunction(Name) 'Converts into SuperFoo which is cast into IFoo
    End Function
```

(if it does not work, use)

```
    Function TryGet(Name as String) as IFoo
        Dim myResult As SuperFoo = InitialTryGetFunction(Name)
        Return myResult
    End Function
```

Comment: That sounds promising and seem to do what I wanted: handle the null reference from inside the SuperFoo Class. Will give it a try and get back to you. Many thanks!

Comment: Verdict: it does not work in my case because Foo is actually an interface (exposed via COM interop), so conversion operators are not available :(. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I did resolve this by creating a regular Shared Function, which does exactly the same as the CType, but has a different name and needs to be called explicitly. Not as pretty but it does the job!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Christoph's answer, I faced a subsequent problem which was that `Foo` is actually an interface itself (exposed via COM interop).

For anyone facing this same issue, here is how I dealt with it:

```
Public Class SuperFoo
    Implements IFoo

    Private ThisFoo As Foo

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(MyFoo As Foo)
        Me.ThisFoo = MyFoo
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetNew(obj as Foo) As SuperFoo
        Return If(obj Is Nothing, Nothing, New SuperFoo(obj))
    End Function

    Public Property Value As String Implements IFoo.Value
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFoo.Value
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.ThisFoo.Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Class AnotherClass

    Function TryGet(Name as String) as IFoo
        Dim MyFoo as Foo = InitialTryGetFunction(Name)
        Return SuperFoo.GetNew(MyFoo)
    End Function

End Class
```

I gave the accepted answer to Christoph as he provided the answer for general cases.

Comment: It should work how I suggested it (at least the alternate version below), as SuperFoo is a managed class and not a COM interface. And there you implement the widening operator.

Comment: .net would not let you widen from an interface into something else. You can widen from an object into an interface but the reverse does not compile. In the end what I am doing is fairly similar to a Factory, albeit the factory is inside the class it instantiates..

Comment: I found the root cause: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc33029. In any cases, thanks again for putting me to the right direction, and I am quite happy using a factory rather than an operator; find it safer.